# How to modify pom.xml without regenerating the whole pom

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

My job is to create a **MavenXpp3Rewriter** class which nearly the same as MavenXpp3Writer but the rewriter shouldn't regenerate the whole pom.xml but just update it.

The MavenXpp3Rewriter will contains a method:
private void rewriteModel(Model model, Model oldModel, String tagName, XmlSerializer serializer)

- model: the new maven model which contains the modifications
- oldModel: old maven model before the modification

I have to overwrite the original pom.xml from the new model. The problem is if I call the writeModel method it empties the pom.xml and starting to regenerate which is too much time in case of large number of poms.

The question is how can I update specific parts of pom?
'specific parts' means the difference between model and olModel.

I hope you understand. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dpn't think it will be faster than rewriting them. To do partial updates you will have to read them, identify the differences and then write the new parts. And when you have to "move down" sections, you will just have to write them too.

Comment: The only approach I see is building a patch file, and then execute this against the xml files, if it's faster... I don't know

Comment: Can you explain the reasons why are you doing such a thing?